# Changes in a GeoJson file do not refresh on the map

Tags: openlayers-3

I create a layer from a GEOJSON file. I made some changes to the file and hope the changes can be reflected on the map. But the map stays the same.

I think i should force the map to reload the JSON file but wonder how to do that.

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and this is how I solved it:

Consider using the vector loader function to handle fetching your geojson files. I've had numerous caching issues not using a vector loading function to fetch geojson files and the method below eliminated that problem. For example:

```
var utils = {
refreshGeoJson: function(source,url) {
  var now = Date.now();
  if (typeof url == 'undefined') {
    url = source.getUrl();
  }
  url += '?t=' + now; //Add current time to prevent browser caching
  console.info('refreshGeoJson url: ' + url);
      this.getJson(url).when({
    ready: function(response) {
      var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
      var features = format.readFeatures(response, {
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
      });
      console.dir(features);
      console.log(features.length);
      source.addFeatures(features);
      source.changed();
    }
     });
},
getJson: function(url) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      when = {},
      onload = function() {
    console.log('xhr.status onload() ' + xhr.status);
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
     console.log('getJson() xhr: ');
     console.dir(xhr);
     console.log('getJson() xhr.response: ');
     console.dir(xhr.response);
              when.ready.call(undefined, JSON.parse(xhr.response));
        }
    if (xhr.status === 404) {
      console.log('file not found! url: ' + url);
      alert("file not found!\n" + url);
    }
      },
      onerror = function() {
        console.info('Cannot XHR ' + JSON.stringify(url));
      };
  //console.log('getJson() - retrieve file url: ' + url);
      xhr.open('GET', url, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('cache-control', 'no-store');
      xhr.onload = onload;
      xhr.onerror = onerror;
      xhr.send(null);
      return {
    when: function(obj) { when.ready = obj.ready; }
    };
}
};

var vectorLoader = function(extent, resolution, projection) {
  utils.refreshGeoJson(this);
}

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: /path-to/myFile.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
      defaultDataProjection :'EPSG:3857' 
    }),
    loader: vectorLoader,
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
});
```

I have a timed function that calls `vectorSouce.clear()` before it reloads the data for that layer.  Calling `.clear()` fires the vector loader function for the map layer.